# Toolkit not encapsulated by a jar

Tags: java, rsa

We are using RSA for user Authentication. 
    We are facing same issues given in above,Sharing the stack trace for your reference below.

```
Could not complete request:org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.Error: **Problem loading Module.4**
Caused by:java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]    ... 79 more
**Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Toolkit not encapsulated by a jar.**
    at com.rsa.jcm.f.hz.a(Unknown Source) [jcmFIPS-6.1.3.3.jar:6.1]
    at com.rsa.jcm.f.js.b(Unknown Source) [jcmFIPS-6.1.3.3.jar:6.1]
    at com.rsa.crypto.jcm.ModuleLoader.a(Unknown Source) [jcmFIPS-6.1.3.3.jar:6.1]
    at com.rsa.crypto.jcm.ModuleLoader.load(Unknown Source) [jcmFIPS-6.1.3.3.jar:6.1]
20:24:06,871 ERROR [com.utxfrmwk.util.ExceptionUtils] (http-CDCUDRIFDAPP1/10.40.18.113:3010-4) Exception raised: : java.lang.Error: Problem loading Module.4
    at com.rsa.cryptoj.o.by.f(Unknown Source) [cryptojcommon-6.1.3.3.jar:6.1.3.3]
    at com.rsa.cryptoj.o.by.c(Unknown Source) [cryptojcommon-6.1.3.3.jar:6.1.3.3]
    at com.rsa.cryptoj.o.cf.a(Unknown Source) [cryptojcommon-6.1.3.3.jar:6.1.3.3]
    at com.rsa.cryptoj.o.ce.b(Unknown Source) [cryptojcommon-6.1.3.3.jar:6.1.3.3]


Looking for your prompt support and cooperation's .
regards 


Ashish
```

Comment: did you mange to resolve it?